# How can I get value when submit form on the vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have two component

My first component like this :

```
<template>
    <div>
        ...
            <form-input id="name" name="name" v-model="name">Name</form-input>
        ...
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" @click="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                name: null
            }
        },
        methods: {
            submit() {
                console.log('submit profile')
                console.log(this.name)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

On the first component, it will call form input component

The form input component like this :

```
<template>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label :for="id" class="col-sm-3 control-label"><slot></slot></label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input :type="type" :name="name" :id="id" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            'id': String,
            'name': String,
            'type': {
                type: String,
                default() {
                    if(this.type == 'number')
                        return 'number'
                    return 'text'
                }
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

I using pattern like that. So the form input component can be used in many components

But my problem here is : I can not retrieve the value when submitting button

I try like that, but the result of `console.log(this.name)` is `null`

I want when input data name and submit form, it will get the name

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the official docs [**Form Input Components using Custom Events**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events):

- Know that `v-model` in the parent is the same as:

  ```html
    <child-component
       v-bind:value="something"
       v-on:input="something = $event.target.value">
  ```

So when using `v-model` you are actually "sending" a `value` prop and "expecting" an `input` event.

To make that happen, then, in the child component do:

- Declare the prop `value`
- Change the `<input>` to have as `:value` the `value` prop declared above
- Change the `<input>` to emit an `input` event to its parent when changing value

Final template:

```html
<template>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label :for="id" class="col-sm-3 control-label"><slot></slot></label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input :type="type" :name="name" :id="id" class="form-control" :value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)">
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            'id': String,
            'name': String,
            'type': {
                type: String,
                default() {
                    if(this.type == 'number')
                        return 'number'
                    return 'text'
                }
            },
            'value': String,
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I want to ask. Whether answer above can be used for textarea, select, radio button, checkbox? So other than input text

Comment: Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49248878/how-can-i-get-value-radio-button-when-submit-form-on-the-vue-component. I make the new question for radio button. Maybe you can help me

Comment: Yes, but in some it'll be `@change` instead.

Comment: Such as in the `<select>`, for instance.

Comment: Okay thanks. It works. How do you think about input type file?

Comment: I think `@change` for `file` as well.