# Why the value of input file missing when I input the another input on the vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have two component

My first component (parent component) like this :

```
<template>
    <div>
        ...
            <form-input id="name" name="name" v-model="name">Name</form-input>
            <form-input id="birth-date" name="birth_date" type="date" v-model="birthDate">Date of Birth</form-input>
            <form-input id="avatar" name="avatar" type="file" v-on:triggerChange="onFileChange($event)">Avatar</form-input>
            <form-input id="mobile-number" name="mobile_number" type="number" v-model="mobileNumber">Mobile Number</form-input>
        ...
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                name: null,
                birthDate:  null,
                mobileNumber: null
            }
        },
        methods: {
            onFileChange(e) {
                let self = this
                this.validate(e.target.files[0])
                .then(function(res) {
                    let files = e.target.files,
                    reader = new FileReader()
                    // if any values
                    if (files.length) {
                        self.removeErrorMessageUpload()
                        self.files = files[0]
                        reader.onload = (e) => {
                            self.updateProfileAvatar(e.target.result)
                        }
                        reader.readAsDataURL(files[0])
                    }
                })
                .catch(function() {
                    // do something in the case where the image is not valid
                    self.displayErrorMessageUpload()
                })
            },
            validate(image) {
                let self = this
                return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                    // validation file type
                    if (!self.allowableTypes.includes(image.name.split(".").pop().toLowerCase())) {
                        reject()
                    }
                    // validation file size
                    if (image.size > self.maximumSize) {
                        reject()
                    }
                    // validation image resolution
                    let img = new Image()
                    img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(image)
                    img.onload = function() {
                        let width = img.naturalWidth,
                            height = img.naturalHeight

                        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src)

                        if (width != 100 && height != 100) {
                            reject()
                        } 
                        else {
                            resolve()
                        }
                    }
                })         
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

From the parent component, it will call child component (form input component)

My child component are input type text, input type date, input type file and input type number. I combine all of them into 1 component

The child component like this :

```
<template>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label :for="id" class="col-sm-3 control-label"><slot></slot></label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input :type="type" :name="name" :id="id" class="form-control" :value="value" v-on:change="applySelected($event)" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)">
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "form-input",
        props: {
            'id': String,
            'name': String,
            'isRequired': {
                type: Boolean,
                default: true
            },
            'type': {
                type: String,
                default() {
                    if(this.type == 'number')
                        return 'number'
                    return 'text'
                }
            },
            'value': {
                type: [String, Number]
            }
        },
        methods: {
            applySelected(e) {
                this.$emit('triggerChange', e)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Because I merge into 1 komponent, I get a new problem

If I input the input type file, the value of file will show in the input type file

But if I input in the input type text, the value of input type file missing

Why the value of input type file missing?

#### Demo:

```js
Vue.component('form-input', {
  template: "#form-input-tpl",
  name: "form-input",
  props: {
    'id': String,
    'name': String,
    'isRequired': {type: Boolean, default: true},
    'type': { type: String, default () {if (this.type == 'number') {return 'number'} else {return 'text'}}},
    'value': { type: [String, Number] }
  },
  methods: {
    applySelected(e) { this.$emit('triggerChange', e) }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    name: null,
    birthDate: null,
    mobileNumber: null
  },
  methods: {
    onFileChange(e) {
      // ...
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<template id="form-input-tpl">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label :for="id" class="col-sm-3 control-label"><slot></slot></label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input :type="type" :name="name" :id="id" class="form-control" :value="value" v-on:change="applySelected($event)" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)">
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <h3>Select a file, then type a name. The file will be reset.</h3>
  <div>
    <form-input id="name" name="name" v-model="name">Name</form-input>
    <form-input id="birth-date" name="birth_date" type="date" v-model="birthDate">Date of Birth</form-input>
    <form-input id="avatar" name="avatar" type="file" v-on:triggerChange="onFileChange($event)">Avatar</form-input>
    <form-input id="mobile-number" name="mobile_number" type="number" v-model="mobileNumber">Mobile Number</form-input>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "Why the value of input type file missing?" conflicts with prior statements, which is is?

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss What do you mean?  I do not understand

Comment: You say "If I input the input type file, the value of file will show in the input type file

But if I input in the input type text, the value of input type file missing

Why the value of input type file missing?" but the sentence "But if I input in the input type text, the value of input type file missing"  What does that mean? The `text` type field is impacting the  `file` type field?  That makes no sense that it happens that one field impacts the other indicating there might be something else at play here.  Note the default html input type is `type="text"` if unspecified.

Comment: Perhaps show the rendered HTML as an additional bit of information.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss This apparently occurs because `v-on:change="applySelected($event)"` or `@input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"`. It's run on the input type text, input type file, input type date and input type number. Because I combine it into 1 component

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss See my question. It had updated with demo. Maybe you can give another solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem is:

> After you have chosen a file in the `<form-input type="file">`, if you type something in the `<form-input type="type">`, the `<form-input type="file">` erases. Why is that?

This happens because when you edit `<form-input type="text">`, Vue will "repaints" the components.

And when it repaints the `<form-input type="file">`, it will go back to "Nothing selected" because it is a new `<input type="file">`.

## Solution: Keeping the files' values

As [Kaiido](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3702797/kaiido) points in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49337786/why-the-value-of-input-file-missing-when-i-input-the-another-input-on-the-vue-co/49343899?noredirect=1#comment85689057_49343899), in [*latest* versions of browsers, you can set](https://github.com/whatwg/html/pull/2866) the files of a `<input type="file">` in a standard way.

So this is what the code below does. It watches for the `value` property (that comes when the parent uses `v-model` and sets its value to the `.files` property of the `<input type="file">`.

We have to use two `<input>` (with `v-if`/`v-else`) because when it is a `<input type="file">`, the `:value` property can be set, the event handler should be different (`@change="$emit('input', $event.target.files)"`) and we want to keep a `ref` so we can set the `files`.

Full **working demo below**.

```js
Vue.component('form-input', {
  template: "#form-input-tpl",
  name: "form-input",
  props: {
    'id': String,
    'name': String,
    'isRequired': {type: Boolean, default: true},
    'type': {type: String, default: 'text'},
    'value': {type: [String, Number, FileList, DataTransfer]}
  },
  mounted() {
    // set files upon creation or update if parent's value changes
    this.$watch('value', () => {
      if (this.type === "file") { this.$refs.inputFile.files = this.value; }
    }, { immediate: true });
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    name: null,
    birthDate: null,
    mobileNumber: null,
    files: null
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<template id="form-input-tpl">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label :for="id" class="col-sm-3 control-label"><slot></slot></label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
           <input v-if="type !== 'file'" :type="type" :name="name" :id="id" class="form-control" :value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)">
            
           <input v-else :type="type" :name="name" :id="id" class="form-control" @change="$emit('input', $event.target.files)" ref="inputFile">
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <form-input id="name" name="name" v-model="name">Name</form-input>
    <form-input id="birth-date" name="birth_date" type="date" v-model="birthDate">Date of Birth</form-input>
    <form-input id="avatar" name="avatar" type="file" v-model="files">Avatar</form-input>
    <form-input id="mobile-number" name="mobile_number" type="number" v-model="mobileNumber">Mobile Number</form-input>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using your `file-change` event and `validate` function:

```js
Vue.component('form-input', {
  template: "#form-input-tpl",
  name: "form-input",
  props: {
    'id': String,
    'name': String,
    'isRequired': {type: Boolean, default: true},
    'type': {type: String, default: 'text'},
    'value': {type: [String, Number, FileList, DataTransfer]}
  },
  mounted() {
    // set files upon creation or update if parent's value changes
    this.$watch('value', () => {
      if (this.type === "file") { this.$refs.inputFile.files = this.value; }
    }, { immediate: true });
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    name: null,
    birthDate: null,
    mobileNumber: null,
    filesVModel: null,
    allowableTypes: ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'],
    maximumSize: 1000,
    files: null
  },
  methods: {
    onFileChange(e) {
      console.log('onfilechange!');
      let self = this
      this.validate(e.target.files[0])
        .then(function(res) {
          let files = e.target.files,
            reader = new FileReader()
          // if any values
          if (files.length) {
            self.removeErrorMessageUpload()
            self.files = files[0]
            reader.onload = (e) => {
              self.updateProfileAvatar(e.target.result)
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(files[0])
          }
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          // do something in the case where the image is not valid
          self.displayErrorMessageUpload(err)
        })
    },
    validate(image) {
      let self = this
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // validation file type
        if (!self.allowableTypes.includes(image.name.split(".").pop().toLowerCase())) {
          reject("Type " + image.name.split(".").pop().toLowerCase() + " is not allowed.")
        }
        // validation file size
        if (image.size > self.maximumSize) {
          reject("Image size " + image.size + " is larger than allowed " + self.maximumSize + ".")
        }
        // validation image resolution
        let img = new Image()
        img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(image)
        img.onload = function() {
          let width = img.naturalWidth,
            height = img.naturalHeight

          window.URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src)

          if (width != 100  && height != 100) {
            reject("Width and height are " + width + " and " + height + " and not both 100")
          } else {
            resolve()
          }
        }
      })
    },
    displayErrorMessageUpload(msg) {
      console.log('displayErrorMessageUpload', msg);
    },
    removeErrorMessageUpload() {
      console.log('removeErrorMessageUpload');
    },
    updateProfileAvatar(result) {
      console.log('updateProfileAvatar', result);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<template id="form-input-tpl">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label :for="id" class="col-sm-3 control-label"><slot></slot></label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
           <input v-if="type !== 'file'" :type="type" :name="name" :id="id" class="form-control" :value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)">
            
           <input v-else :type="type" :name="name" :id="id" class="form-control" @change="$emit('input', $event.target.files)" ref="inputFile" v-on:change="$emit('file-change', $event)">
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <form-input id="name" name="name" v-model="name">Name</form-input>
    <form-input id="birth-date" name="birth_date" type="date" v-model="birthDate">Date of Birth</form-input>
    <form-input id="avatar" name="avatar" type="file" v-model="filesVModel" @file-change="onFileChange">Avatar</form-input>
    <form-input id="mobile-number" name="mobile_number" type="number" v-model="mobileNumber">Mobile Number</form-input>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [You can](https://github.com/whatwg/html/pull/2866) (in latest browsers) set the `files` property of an `input[type=file]` to an other FileList. I don't know vue.js so wouldn't be able to catch the rendering event myself nor to access the new input, but just to let you know that it's actually doable.

Comment: @Kaiido humm, I actually knew it was doable through a glitch or something. Since it was non standard (at least not supported by `v-model`) I thought it wasn’t worth pursuing. But thanks for letting us know, having a standard way of doing it in newer browsers is great news!

Comment: @acdcjunior Is there no other way? I am using required html5. If using your way, it will always show validation html5. And whether I can  send the file selected to server side using your way?

Comment: Hey, guys, thanks for the push :) I ended up researching a bit more and I think the final version is quite clean! It sets the `.files` using standard interface! No hacks! I learned a lot in the process! Thanks a lot! @ SuccessMan @Kaiido

Comment: @acdcjunior You are welcome. I will try it. Btw, what do you mean by `immediate: true`?

Comment: @SuccessMan Using it like that, basically makes the watcher be executed when the component is created (watchers don't execute on creation by default). And since I want that piece of code to be executed on `mounted`, I also use `Vue.nextTick()`. (The only place I know about `immediate` in the docs is https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch )

Comment: Btw, I just changed the watcher. I think the way it is now is cleaner and safer.

Comment: @acdcjunior Okay thanks. Now i'm trying your way. Do you delete onFileChange method in the parent component? I using the method to validate file type, file size and file resolution. If it deleted, how can I validate it? Try to see my question. I added the contents of onFileChange method. It used to validate the image

Comment: You can add it back. I removed because I thought you were using to keep the value (which it is keeping using the watcher now). When adding back, just make sure you `$emit('file-change', ...)` and `v-on:file-change` (use `-` instead of camelCase), because it is less error prone.

Comment: @acdcjunior Can you update your answer with onFileChange method. I had try it. But if upload image, on the console exist error like this : `Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "value". Expected String, Number, FileList, got File.
`, `Error in callback for watcher "value": "TypeError: Failed to set the 'files' property on 'HTMLInputElement': The provided value is not of type 'FileList'."`, `Failed to set the 'files' property on 'HTMLInputElement': The provided value is not of type 'FileList'.`

Comment: @acdcjunior What do you think about that error? I want to receive your answer, but still not perfect

Comment: @acdcjunio In the chrome browser. Try to add back onFileChange method to check the error

Comment: @acdcjunior I am pessimistic I can check the validation using your way

Comment: I have added a second snippet using the functions you mention. Check it out.

Comment: @acdcjunior Okay thanks. It seems it works. I want to ask again. Do you know how to clear value in the input file type if validation fails. I tried like this : `.catch(function() {
    self.displayErrorMessageUpload()
    self.filesVModel = null
    self.$refs.inputFile.files = null
})`. There exist error like this : `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'files' of undefined`

Comment: @acdcjunior I had find a solution to clear the input type file. Btw, thanks for your help. You are great. Now it work